# Group operation in generator-relator representation

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group of order $n$ given by generator-relator representation.

**Question :** Let $a$ and $b$ are two elements of $G$ and we want to know the result of $ab$.

Is there any way to know the result, without writing down the group as a table?

What other information I need to store so that I can get the result of the $ab$($a$ group operation $b$)?

Comment: Write them both in terms of the generators and multiply them. Simplify using the relations of the representation, if necessary.

Comment: If you expect to be able to tell if $ab$ is equal to a given element $c$, all given in terms of the generators, then this is not possible in general. But in practice this is not a big deal.

Comment: @ Morgan Rodgers  I can write both in terms of generator but how to multiply after that.

Comment: What does it even mean "to know the result of $ab$"? There are many ways of writing $ab$ in the generators. Which one is "the result"? What's wrong with just "$ab$"?

Comment: @ verret  the element which corresponds to the element.

Comment: @verret The subtlety is that $ab$ is not a group element, but rather represents a group element. I guess its hard to answer the question without more details, but I presume the formal set up is that every group element is "nominated" a single representative word in the generators, and the question is "can we determine which representative word corresponds to the product $ab$?".

Comment: @user1729 So is a canonical list of elements part of the input, on top of the presentation?

Comment: @verret I guess so (key word is "guess"). This then makes it a generalized version of the word problem, as the process to solve this problem is to go along the list asking "is $ab$ equal to $c_1$? $c_2$?...", while the standard version of the word problem is to take $b$ and $c$ to be the empty word $\epsilon$, and ask "is $a=\epsilon$?" (There are other ways to linking this to the word problem, obviously, as you are really asking "is $abc_1=\epsilon$? $abc_2=\epsilon$?...".)

Comment: @Print_lol I do not think this question should be reopened as it is currently unclear. It needs to be made more formal. Do you understand the exchange between verret and myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called "[the word problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_problem_for_groups)", and it is hard. In some finitely presented groups it is actually undecidable. Of course, for finite groups you can always check by hand or write algorithms that terminate, giving you an answer. But it is not much different from "writing down the group as a table" (and in fact it is harder than that).

Comment: What are the other things which one needs to store such that multiplication can be done.

Comment: What do you mean? Multiplication can always be done, it is a group. The problem is knowing you multiplied "as much as you could" (i.e. arriving at a so-called "reduced word"), and even then it is not clear how to investigate whether different reduced words identify the same element